# Bootstrap input-append + Google Maps form

Tags: google-maps, input, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a block-level input-append, where the input bar takes up all the space other than the button.

I got this working with a `<button>` or `<span>`, but once I switched the tag to an `<input>`, I started having styling issues again. However, the `<input>` tag is required.

I've include a [Fiddle - HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
.input-append {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.add-on {
  display: table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
}
.input-bar {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  border-right-style: None;
}
.well{
  padding-right: 58px;
}​
```

1. I removed the nested selectors as you can't do that in regular CSS. (With Sass and LESS you can though).
2. I added "height: auto !important" to the ".add-on" selector. Although it's generally regarded not best practice to use "!important".
3. I added padding-right to the well of 58px which is the width of the GO! button, 39px, plus the well padding of 19px.

**Edit:** As @nicefinly pointed out, the height of the GO! button was still off. In Chrome I didn't see anything wrong, but in Firefox I could definitely see the height problem.

So, with all of [his changes](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/43/), I would also add that when modifying the well and add-on classes for example, this would change all the places where those standard Bootstrap classes are used and this is probably not want you want.

Instead, I would create separate classes for all of these custom classes so they work in this specific case and elsewhere it works as intended. For example, "add-on-button", "well-with-button", etc.

Comment: That seems to fix the width, but the height is a few pixels off it seems - [as seen in the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/34/) However... I should thank you as this pointed me in the right direction. I wrote out my own answer as well for future readers.

Comment: Only major difference I did was set the height static, as opposed to auto. Compare [JSFiddle of auto](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/32/) with a the [static height](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/36/)

Comment: This is also helpful in case future readers have the same problem or a similar problem with non-input buttons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896782/twitter-bootstrap-block-level-form

Comment: Found solution. Separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

@CoderDave pointed me in the right direction with his suggestion - [JSFiddle of @CoderDave's answer](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/34/)

However, I then noticed that the height was somewhat off. Instead, I set the button height manually - [JSFiddle of my workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/36/)

```
.input-append {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.add-on {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 30px !important;
}
.input-bar {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  border-right-style: None;
}
.well{
  padding-right: 58px;
}
​
```

**BUT THEN...**

Testing in Chrome gave me strange results (not necessarily in the fiddle, but in my local environment). Therefore, instead of padding, I used the `margin-left` and `margin-right` where

`margin-left = 17px` on the `input .add-on`

and

`margin-right = -55px` on the `.input-bar`

**However...** After that, I noticed that the z-index was causing the `.input-bar` to block out the GO! button when the bar was in focus (i.e. I clicked into it).

Therefore, I set `z-index`

`z-index: -1` for the `well`
`z-index: 1` for the `.input-bar`
`z-index: 2` for the `.add-on`

[**FINAL JSFIDDLE HERE!**](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/TrVXE/43/)

This seems like a pretty hacky solution. If anyone has a better solution, please share.

Comment: Yet another update - z-index seems to need adjustment after this.