# Form controls input with input-append (Twitter Bootstrap) break layout

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i'm currently working with Twitter Bootstrap creating forms.

For styling an file input i'm using input-append:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" name="product[picture]-input" id="picture" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Produktbild (optional)">
    <button class="btn" id="picture-reset" type="button"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
    <button class="btn" id="picture-select" type="button">...</button>
</div>
```

But i don't get the styling fit to other inputs. I'm using the responsive design and i tried the relative sizing with

```
class="input-medium"
```

or the grid-sizing with

```
class="span4"
```

but it seems that input-append not optimized for. The full code you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6cvYr/

And here some screens with different screen-sizes, in each size it won't fit:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByywF8ZXCU9kbTdUZ1N6bkxodGs&usp=sharing

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896782/twitter-bootstrap-block-level-form

Comment: i've tried this, but it don't work because of the responsive design....